UIProgressView not updating progress
Simple question, here's the code snippet in question:
override func viewDidLoad()  {
      tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0
      self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
      self.parent?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Please wait", message: "Loading stats...", preferredStyle: .alert)
      let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
      alertView.view.addSubview(progressView)
      present(alertView, animated: true, completion: { [self] in
          DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
              progressView.progress = 0.0
              print(progressView.progress)
              refreshStatData()
              progressView.progress = 0.5
              print(progressView.progress)
              refreshStatDisplay()
              progressView.progress = 1.0
              print(progressView.progress)
              alertView.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
              tableView.isHidden = false
          }
      })
  }

Instead of being blank, then half blue and finally completely filled, the progress bar is grey with 50% progress from the beginning, then it turns blue and then it's gone. I'm not familiar with DispatchQueue so any help would be greatly appreciated.

All of the code in the dispatched closure will execute before the progress view is refreshed on screen because that code is running on the main thread and the main thread won't be available for the ui update until it has finished. If you want several delayed updates to your progress view, use a Timer

There are lots of problems with your code. The biggest problem is that you are misusing UIAlertController. The docs say:
"The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and doesn’t support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."
The important bit there is that a UIAlertController's view hierarchy is private and must not be modified. Avoid Apple's "You must not do XYZ" statements at your peril. And your code that attempts to do multiple updates to your progress bar is all wrong as well, as @Paulw11 mentions in their comment.

You probably also don't want to use an Alert for displaying a progress bar. An alert is a modal which notifies the user of something that happened (something that completed, possibly failed, or which notifies about an irregular state in the app), and which requires user interaction. Usuallly, the modal's context (not the whole app, though) is then in an "idle" state until the user decides what to do. You may present a progress bar as an overlay over the view which displays the data or current state.
